# Color in red diffrencies between two pictures

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm a beginner in python and i have some difficulties to do what i want to do.

I want to spot the difference between two images in a game "spot seven diffenrecies".

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageChops

a = Image.open("pict1.jpg")
b = Image.open("pict2.jpg")
diff = ImageChops.difference (a, b)
```

Now i want to enlight in red the differences like that:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cDh3.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXgzG.jpg

Can you help me (and my awesome english) ? :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest, from where you are above you could do something like:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageChops

a = Image.open("pict1.jpg")
b = Image.open("pict2.jpg")
diff = ImageChops.difference (a, b)
RED = ('red')
RL = Image.new('RGB', diff.size, RED) # Make a red layer the same size
RedDiff = ImageChops.multiply(RL, diff)
Result = ImageChops.blend(RedDiff, b, 0.7)
Result.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Tank you but i get an error [TypeError: an integer is required] http://imgur.com/m1Tlgec

Comment: Make sure that the source images have the same mode. If not, convert them to e.g. 'RGB' before comparing. Also, the statement `RED = ('red')` is redundant. Just replace the reference to `RED` in the following statement by `'red'`.

Answer (score 0):

try to read your images to separate arrays
and compare arrays together

then manipulate the diff parts by change the color you want